# Proof that the sequence $a_n=\frac{3n+2}{n^2+1}$ converges using the Epsilon N proof

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> Give a forma Epsilon-N proof that the sequence converges to 0
>   $$a_n=\frac{3n+2}{n^2+1}$$
>   Hints only!

I find myself still unfamiliarised and uncomfortable with having to deal with the Epsilon-N proof. It might be good to understand the basic it once and for all.

Attempt: 
$$\left|\frac{3n+2}{n^{2}+1}-0\right|< \epsilon$$
At this point I know that for the limit of the sequence to hold, I need 
$$n\leq N$$ but have no idea how to proceed further.

What question(s) should I be asking myself at this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So notice that the sequence is positive for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so you can get rid of the absolute value bars.  From there, we have $\displaystyle \frac{3n+2}{n^2+1} < \varepsilon \iff 3n+2 < \varepsilon(n^2 + 1)$.

So from this we can get an inequality involving a quadratic (this is where your algebra/pre-calculus knowledge will come in handy).  You can show that that inequality is satisfied for all values of $n$ sufficiently large (specifically how large will be in terms of epsilon).

Comment: I'm not getting a sensible answer after reducing. I had mathematica made that confirmation.

Comment: There's no need for Mathematica - you won't have a numerical.  So working with the inequality, we get $\varepsilon n^2 - 3n + (\varepsilon - 1) > 0$, right?  And this is the graph of some parabola which looks like ____?  And so how do we guarantee the inequality?  $n$ needs to be larger than ___?  Remember, we are searching for a value $N$ -- in terms of the given $\varepsilon$ -- such that whenever $n \geq N$, then the inequality holds (and thus $a_n < \varepsilon$).

Comment: It's basically a parabola that cuts the y-axis at $$(\epsilon-1)$$.
n needs to be larger than N.

Comment: Ok, and it's pointing in which direction, given that $\varepsilon > 0$?  Also I accidentally had a number of typos.  First, meant to write "numerical answer" in my first comment above.  Second, I realized it was "3n+2" and not "3n+1" in the numerator, so that'll change things slightly in my first comment.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Edit:typo error

Comment: The parabola is pointing downwards(smiley face)

Comment: I don't think that value of $N$ works unfortunately, but we're almost done.  Can you see why the value of $N$ will be the rightmost root of the parabola (where it crosses the $x$-axis)?

Comment: I don't. In fact, I'm still mulling over the "answer" from the quadratic solution.

Comment: Ok, so from the inequality in my original post, we get $\varepsilon n^2 - 3n + (\varepsilon - 2) > 0$.  The left hand side is a quadratic whose graph is a parabola, and we want to find values of $n$ for which it is positive.  So if the graph of the parabola is pointing so that it looks like a smiley-face, then the $N$ we choose is going to be the rightmost zero, since everything to the right of that rightmost zero is positive.

Comment: This was my quadratic solution $$\frac{3\pm \sqrt{9-4\epsilon(\epsilon-2)}}{2 \epsilon }\leq 0$$

Comment: Yes!  That's very close.  Something's going awry inside the square root though.  $b^2 - 4ac = 9 - 4 \varepsilon( \varepsilon - 2)$.  Anyways, those values are the two roots of the parabola, and we want to take the rightmost one.  For values of $n$ greater than the rightmost one, the original inequality will be positive.

Comment: I actually expanded the terms in the square root hence it differ from yours.

Comment: What do you mean by for n values greater than the right most one?

Comment: The parabola has two roots.  Anyways, I've given you a good starting point.  I have to go for now, and I'll give you time to think about and absorb what we're doing here.

Comment: Thank you. I will think through.

Answer (score 0):

See it as an inequality where you have to solve for $n$.

Comment: In order to get an "N" out,
$$\frac{3n+2}{n^{2}+1}< \frac{5}{n}\leq \frac{5}{N}$$
I know that for $$n \leq N$$, it must be true that $$5/n \leq 5/N$$

Answer (score 0):

You could also use
$$0\le\frac{3n+2}{n^2+1} \le \frac{3n+3}{n^2-1} = \frac{3(n+1)}{(n+1)(n-1)} = \frac3{n-1}.$$

So now you only need to find an $N$ such that
$$\frac3{n-1}<\epsilon$$
for $n\ge N$.

(We should be a bit careful: This works only for $n\ge1$, since for $n=1$ we have zero in the denominator. But this should not cause much trouble - limit of a sequence is not influenced by changing finite number of terms. We can simply add the condition that $N>1$ and we are fine.)